# using PERFORM to insert a string of SELECT statement into a temp table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to insert data into a temp_table and then truncating the table after analyzing the result.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validation()
  RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE counter INTEGER;
DECLARE minsid INTEGER;
DECLARE maxsid INTEGER;
DECLARE rec RECORD;
DECLARE stmt varchar;
BEGIN
  SELECT MIN(sid) INTO minsid FROM staging.validation;
  SELECT MAX(sid) INTO maxsid FROM staging.validation;

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (col1 TEXT, col2 INTEGER, col3 BOOLEAN) ON COMMIT DROP;

  FOR counter IN minsid..maxsid LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Counter: %', counter;
    SELECT sql INTO stmt FROM staging.validation WHERE sid = counter;

    RAISE NOTICE 'sql: %', stmt;

    PERFORM 'INSERT INTO temp_table (col1, col2, col3) ' || stmt;

    IF temp_table.col3 = false THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'there is a false value';
    END IF;

  END LOOP;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Whenever I run this function
`SELECT * FROM validation();`
I get an error:

`ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "temp_table" Where: PL/pgSQL function validation() line 21 at IF`

Here is how my staging.validation table looks -

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bXO9gqFS-GtcC1qJtgNbFkR6ygOuPtR_RZoU7VNhgrI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your SQL is with the type (or return type).

In

```
SELECT * FROM validation();
```

You are using `validation()` as if the returned value from the function were a table. But you defined the function to return a single value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validation()
  RETURNS text AS $$
```

So, the said function can't be used in the `FROM` clause.

If you are trying to use the side-effects of the function (`PERFORM 'INSERT INTO ...`), then you can use it in the SELECT list directly, e.g.

```
SELECT validation();
```

If you really intend to use the returned relation, then you need to make `validation` a Set Returning Function (SRF).

--EDIT--

In addition to the return type issue, another error in the `IF` statement is causing the actual error message (rather than the error in return type, which needs to be fixed as well).

If I understand what you are looking for (e.g. to test whether `col3 = false` for some rows in `temp_table`), one way that I think can achieve it, is to use a query, e.g.:

```
IF (SELECT 1 FROM temp_table WHERE  col3 = false) = 1 THEN
  RAISE NOTICE 'there is a false value';
END IF;
```

The subquery `(SELECT 1 FROM temp_table WHERE  col3 = false)` returns 1 if FALSE exists, and `NULL` otherwise.

I don't think it's valid to use `temp_table.col3` directly.

Comment: I think the issue is with IF condition, as even `SELECT validation();` gives me the same error.

Comment: @hky404 You're right. It seems that another error which directly causes the error message. Please see my edit.